# Bootstrap Modal Events Not Firing with Joint.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, jointjs

I've noticed when trying to used the Bootstrap Modal events (i.e. 'hidden.bs.modal') they don't fire when I'm using the Joint.js library.  Is there a work-around for this?

Comment: please provide some code you have.

Comment: It's not about my code.  It's about a conflict between the two libraries. Joint.js overrides Bootstraps modal events.

Comment: I still don't have a solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it was because I was using `joint.all.js` which has a version of jQuery already included (thus causing me to have two references to jQuery on the same page). I removed jQuery from this js file and my Bootstrap modal worked fine.